# Error on starting Blueman

Tags: arch-linux, bluetooth

I'm trying to get Blueman working on a surface pro 6 with Arch. Whenever the applet starts up I get this error message. The weird thing is everything seems to work fine but I don't want an error popping up whenever I `startx`.

```
g-dbus-error-quark: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Failed: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/blueman/main/DbusService.py", line 125, in _handle_method_call
    ok(method(*args))   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/blueman/plugins/mechanism/Network.py", line 49, in _reload_network
    nc = NetConf.get_default()   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/blueman/main/NetConf.py", line 283, in get_default
    if not isinstance(obj.ip4_address, str) and obj.ip4_address is not None: AttributeError: 'NetConf' object has no attribute 'ip4_address'  (0)
```

Any ideas on what I can do to get this sorted?

I'm running the custom kernel `5.3.18-1-surface` and the `surface-pro-6-firmware` package. So I shouldn't have any missing firmware.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error running Archlabs with Openbox.

I stopped the error popup by uninstalling Blueman and then deleting the `/var/lib/blueman/network.state` file. Then I reinstalled Blueman and rebooted.

The error popup hasn't reoccurred yet.